# Access Python enum value from class method

Tags: python-3.x, class, enums

I have an Enum as follows:

```
class RequestMethodVerbMapping(Enum):
    POST = 'Create'
    PUT = 'Update'
    DELETE = 'Delete'
```

Now, in order to access the string associated with a certain HTTP verb, I do the following:

```
In [19]: RequestMethodVerbMapping.POST.value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[19]: 'Create'
```

Works as expected.However, now the HTTP verb is a class attribute and I want to access the enum in a class method. I did the following:

```
import RequestMethodVerbMapping

class BaseWorkFlow:
    def __init__(self, request_method):
        self.request_method = request_method

def print_enum(self):
    print (RequestMethodVerbMapping.self.request_method.value)
```

However, this does not work and gives me an error:

> AttributeError: self

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the Enum value by the attribute name should do the job:

```
def print_enum(self):
    print(getattr(RequestMethodVerbMapping, self.request_method).value)
```

Comment: No..request_method is not an enum..request_method is actually Django's request method which returns POST,PUT etc. I then use that to find the appropriate string using my Enum..

Comment: @Amistad gotcha, how about this version?